# how to replace "/" in a POSIX sh string

Tags: linux, string, shell, ash

To replace substring  in the bash string `str` I use:

```
str=${str/$pattern/$new}
```

However, I'm presently writing a script which will be executed with `ash`.

I have a string containing `'/'` and I want to use the above syntax inorder to replace the `'/'` in my string but it does not work.

I tried:

```
str=${str///a}
str=${str/\//a}
str=${str/'/'/a}
```

But they do not work

How I can fix that?

Comment: For what it's worth, `ash` implements this nowadays.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This parameter expansion is a bash extension to POSIX sh. If you review [the relevant section of IEEE standard 1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02), you'll see that it isn't a required feature, so shells which promise only POSIX compliance, such as `ash`, have no obligation to implement it, and no obligation for their implementations to hew to any particular standard of correctness should they do so anyhow..

If you want bash extensions, you need to use bash (or other ksh derivatives which are extended similarly).

In the interim, you can use other tools. For instance:

```
str=$(printf '%s' "$str" | tr '/' 'a')
```

or

```
str=$(printf '%s' "$str" | sed -e 's@/@a@g')
```

Comment: @Anis_Stack The POSIX shell language doesn't require it to work at all. Look at the list of expansions in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html -- you'll see that `${foo//bar/baz}` isn't on the list.

Comment: @Anis_Stack ...and since `ash` only promises to be compatible with POSIX sh, and POSIX sh doesn't require the feature, any implementation that's only half-baked isn't even a bug, it's just unspecified behavior.

Comment: Some old versions of sed need an endline, or they don't give any output, thus `str=$(printf '%s\n' "$str"|tr / a)` . Trivial strings like `/` or `a` don't need to be escaped with apostrophes (`'`).

Comment: @JaakkoSalomaa, I agree, but it's better to encourage overquoting rather than underquoting. Format strings in particular often contain backslashes, and those _do_ need to be in single quotes to be treated literally; encouraging habitual use means folks don't make mistakes in other common cases.

Answer (score 4):

POSIX string substitutions can be used to create a 100% POSIX compatible function that does the replacement. For short strings, this is considerably faster than command substitution, especially under Cygwin, whose `fork(2)` copies the parent process's address space on top of creating processes being generally slow in Windows.

```
replace_all() {
    RIGHT=$1
    R=

    while [ -n "$RIGHT" ]; do
        LEFT=${RIGHT%%$2*}

        if [ "$LEFT" = "$RIGHT" ]; then
            R=$R$RIGHT
            return
        fi

        R=$R$LEFT$3
        RIGHT=${RIGHT#*$2}
    done
}
```

It works like this:

```
$ replace_all ' foo bar baz ' ' ' .
$ echo $R
.foo.bar.baz.
```

With regards to performance, replacing 25% of characters in a 512 byte string runs roughly 50 times faster with `replace_all()` than command substitution under the Cygwin `dash(1)`. However, the execution time evens out around 4 KiB.

Comment: This is the correct solution if strictly posix is needed. Clever and elegant.

Comment: @FWDekker, the quotes you edited in aren't in Open Group's POSIX reference's examples, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

I don't know if they're unsupported anywhere, but I'd rather keep the example conforming to the standard's example so I know it's POSIX. Do you mind if I unroll your edit?